# Using AWK how can I total lines that match?

Tags: parsing, awk, iostat

I'm trying to total the value of lines matching nvme* hhd from iostat in megabytes then awking to get total from line x to line z, in my case 2 lines.

```
iostat -m  <-- in megabytes

iostat -m |  awk '{if($1 ~ /nvme*/ ) print $2, $3, $4}'

------------------
9.38,   0.20,  0.57

13.67,  0.01,  1.60
------------------- 
23.05, 0.21, 2.17  <<-- The total
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Just add the numbers as you see them to variables keeping the total and print those out in an `END` block.

Comment: Can you please clearly post your source data, and an example of the output you're trying to achieve?  The `iostat` command on my systems does not produce output that includes "nvme".

Comment: Etan, that's the question: How is it done with variable? It's a different value per line so how are both lines totaled as a variable. I've tried several ways and doesn't compute.

Comment: Ghoti, that is the source. Not sure what you mean by "does not produce output". It correctly reports the interface from iostat and that isn't the issue anyway, I'm trying to get totals. The command works perfectly in other words.

Comment: @Queasy, on my system, the `iostat` command does not have a `-m` option.  If you post a question that depends on specific input, you'll get better answers if you actually provide the test input you're trying to process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
iostat -m |  awk '$1 ~ /nvme*/{a+=$2;b+=$3;c+=$4;print $2, $3, $4} END{print"--------------";print a,b,c}'
```

#### How it works

- `$1 ~ /nvme*/`

  This selects the lines whose first field matches the regex `nvme*`.  My `iostat` produces no lines that contain `nvme`.  Consequently, it is up to you to determine if this is really the right regex for your case.
- `a+=$2;b+=$3;c+=$4`

  This keeps a running sum of the three columns of interest in the variables `a`, `b`, and `c`.
- `print $2, $3, $4`

  This prints the three columns of interest.
- `END{print"--------------";print a,b,c}`

  After all lines have been read in, this prints out the total.  The `print"--------------"` produces a nice looking table on my system.  If your `iostat` produces output in a different format, you may need to adjust accordingly.

Comment: Thanks John! I understand it better now as well :-).

Comment: Change it a little but works great.  iostat -m |  awk '$1 ~ /nvme*/{a+=$2;b+=$3;c+=$4}END{print a,b,c}'